# How to sort by summed column in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I can't figure this out.  I have a query pulling data from a couple sources.  The first two columns are [Number of Questions Asked] and [Here's More Clicked].  The third column is a sum of these two columns, [Total Hits]. I'm trying to order by this summed total column.

However, when I do my ORDER BY [Total Hits] DESC and run the query, the query asks me to enter [Total Hits].  What am I doing wrong?

[Total Hits] is a variable created in the query.   I'm doing the following to calculate [Total Hits] in the query.

```
(IIf(IsNull([Number of Questions Asked]),0,[Number of Questions Asked])+IIf(IsNull([Here's More Clicked]),0,[Here's More Clicked])) AS [Total Hits]
```

Comment: Could I suggest a useful function for your calculations? You could use `Nz([Number of Questions Asked], 0)` in place of `Iif(IsNull([Number of Questions Asked]), 0, [Number of Questions Asked])` (they mean the same thing) and save yourself some keystrokes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure, and its been a while using Access.  However, can you specify the oridinal column position that your "Total Hits" column represents in the query...  ex: if its the 5th field,  use   "order by 5"

Comment: Your other alternative is to repeat the calculation in the `Order By` clause. This is actually the SQL standard (though some DBMSs implement an extension that lets you get around it): Aliases from the `Select` clause aren't available in other clauses, though aliases from the `From` clause are.

Comment: Roland, even though another answer has been accepted (inferior to your comment, in my opinion), you really should post the content of your comment as an answer, as it's much more informative (and more complete), in my opinion.